# How to remove McAfee antivirus

Tags: windows, anti-virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

McAfee put its anti-virus software on my computer, and it will only let me get on facebook after I pay big money to take it off! What can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: Please follow the steps there. If they don't work for you, report back with more details of what you've tried.

Comment: @slhck Brenda seems to have the opposite problem; too much antivirus and no virus. Unless this is a virus posing as McAfee, which actually wouldn't surprise me at all.

Comment: OMG NO FACEBOOK!??!?!  OH NOOOOZ, now what are you going to do???? ;)  McAfee wouldn't put it on there; either you did, someone that worked on your computer did, it came with the computer, or it's Malware pretending to be McAfee.  Have you tried Add/Remove Programs to uninstall it?

Comment: @LordTorgamus Malware pretending to be McAfee sounds reasonable. I think the procedure to get rid of it is the same though. Brenda, did you ever actively install McAfee? Do you know you installed a genuine version?

Comment: Yeah, Mcafee isn't going to charge you to get on facebook... But a fake AV program may... If this is your home PC and you didn't put it there, then you most likely have malware pretending to be AV software.

Comment: Is it something like [this](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-win-7-antispyware-2012)? I think a new type of that virus was just released, as I had to remove it from my cousin's computer last night.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don’t have McAfee, but some sort of fake scareware. Try [MS Safety Scanner](http://www.microsoft.com/security/scanner) to get rid of it.

Comment: Better to use MS offline scanner boot media...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline